# android layout multiple spinners next to each other

Tags: android, android-layout

i have the following xml file for my mini image editing app:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.imageeditor.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Dateispinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:entries="@array/Datei" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Bearbeitenspinner2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/DEspinner4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/DEspinner4"
        android:entries="@array/Bearbeiten" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Werkzeugespinner3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Dateispinner1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Dateispinner1"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:entries="@array/Werkzeuge" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/DEspinner4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Dateispinner1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Dateispinner1"
        android:layout_marginTop="102dp"
        android:entries="@array/DE" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

i want these spinners just next to each other and they should look sth like this in the end:

[image: layout]

i tried it also with different layouts. but sofar with no success. what am i doing wrong? maybe using spinners is not the best option?? am open to ideas.

thanks!

Comment: `android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Dateispinner1"` REMOVE THIS LINE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linear layout with `weight`. Change weight as per your requirement.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="Horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.imageeditor.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Dateispinner1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:entries="@array/Datei" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Bearbeitenspinner2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:entries="@array/Bearbeiten" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Werkzeugespinner3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:entries="@array/Werkzeuge" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/DEspinner4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:entries="@array/DE" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Given Answer not Justify the Question.

You remove this Line for widgets will work for you no need to change whole xml.

`android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Dateispinner1"`

This Property Align spinner left to given @+id/Dataspinner1. So removing this will have no reference .

Better to give data spinner 2 property `android:layout_below="@+id/Dateispinner1"` ,

Data spinner 3 Property `android:layout_below="@+id/Dateispinner2"` and so on.

will work 100 %

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this :

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Dateispinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:entries="@array/Datei" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Bearbeitenspinner2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:entries="@array/Bearbeiten" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Werkzeugespinner3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:entries="@array/Werkzeuge" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/DEspinner4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:entries="@array/DE" />

</LinearLayout>
```